# issue storing username and password with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to python and programming at all.

I would like to save my user name and my password when using selenium chrome web driver.

I have added some lines to fill the fields on the log in page, but it will not store the input as with my usual chrome browser.

I also marked the checkbox to save my login information on this computer before clicking "login", but it still asks everytime for user name and password, and also for the authentication code which gets sent to my mail address.

The problem here is, the user should not have to enter the username + password into the code so everyone could see it. I would rather like to let the user type in their username and password manually, with the first launch via chrome web driver only and make it possible that they can check "save my data and don't ask again on this computer".

This is what my code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver.get("https://www.easports.com/en/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/"

time.sleep(10)

btn_login_app = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/button[1]")
btn_login_app.click()

txt_field_email = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
txt_field_email.send_keys("MYEMAIL")
txt_field_pass = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
txt_field_pass.send_keys("MYPASSWORD")
btn_login_ea = driver.find_elemnt_by_id("btnLogin")
btn_login_ea.click()
```

After that, the webpage requires my to enter my security token which gets send to my email account.

That's what I want to avoid. Because the finished program will be only running on their machine and so it is safe to actually save this data without having to re-enter everything over and over again.

Comment: _new to python and programming at all_ doesn't help us to understand your problem. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59157383/edit).

Comment: Sorry, i tried to explain as clear as possible. When you enter your user name and password on a homepage. You normally can say "save this information and dont ask me again" same for 2-factor-auth which is popping up after entering user name and password.  I want to store my data in the chromedriver browser so I can skip the user name+password step and also the step with the auth. code after that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what OP is trying to tell his issue.

But currently, webdrivers are configured to run always on a NEW SESSION/NEW PROFILE.
Meaning, every instance of execution you made, you are always launching the browser as NEW/FRESH, so everything you do from the previous tests will not be retained.

However, there is a way, for example on Chrome webdriver, you can use the selenium capability and add an existing Chrome Profile from your local machine. *Make sure to pre load and save the credentials first on your browser to save it, manually.*

Please use `user-data-dir` parameter on your webdriver capability with the full path of your google chrome profile.

For example in java:

```
String chromeProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir", chromeProfilePath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```